Need to set up Time Machine for 2 MBP to a Windows server - need help
While I've researched and found some answers about similar setups, none have really touched on using a full-on Windows server (Dell PowerEdge R730xd attached to a Dell PowerVault M1200 that houses 9 (8+1 spare) Seagate Iron Wolf Pro 22TB drives in a RAID 0 configuration.
The server was set up with Windows Server, and then, using VMWare, virtual machines (Windows 10 Pro) were set up for various tasks/purposes—most of which involve saving information being downloaded/backed up to a delegated file share drive that has holders for the different tasks.
I access the server either by Microsoft RDT from my MBP M2 Max (8TB internal SSD, 64gb RAM, running Ventura 13.5.2.
I have attempted to set up a VM on the server so I could install an OSX emulator and Ventura OS (following the process I found here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/macos-windows-10-virtual-machine/) and couldn't get past step 4 - for whatever reason, the clean ISO of Ventura OS would not install. I tried using Monterey instead, creating a new ISO. It would not install either. So, right now I am stuck.
I've thought about figuring out how to attach a dedicated external hard drive to the server for Time Machine, but because of the RAID configuration, when Windows sees a drive that is formatted in TM's desirable format, it immediately wants to format the drive.
Then, I tried ditching Time Machine altogether and using a different software - Carbon Copy Cloner (with a free trial) that is installed on my MBP and can connect to the server through the network. However, I have not found a way to successfully have the specific folders in the file share drive to automatically connect upon booting my MBP, causing me to manually reset each destination drive EVERY time the software runs. That is irritating and not feasible.
There has to be a way to solve this. I would be most appreciative of some solid advice to solve this headache.
Is there a newer technology or method that I can learn about, or maybe someone has already answered this kind of question in a remote corner of this forum?

You have a RAID-0!? You do realize that that has no redundancy and if one drive fails you lose EVERYTHING? Also you will need to backup to HFS+ disk images which you can place in any share that the Mac can attach to.

Sorry, I mistyped - it is not RAID 0. There is a redundancy set up. It is set up so if a drive fails then the spare drive will be added to the array and carry on. :)

I respect people that want to roll their own backup solution, but this will not be an easy problem to solve. Hiring out your software needs to CCC or Super Duper or BackBlaze is the most efficient way once you give up on Time Machine. Let me know if you want an answer on how to not do what you ask but still solve the issue of network backups

This is from an Apple Support article:

If your network server or NAS device supports Time Machine Bonjour notifications, you can set up Time Machine backups even if you are not connected to the server. If your server does not support Time Machine Bonjour notifications, you may still be able to set it up as a Time Machine destination by connecting to the server using SMB and then selecting the mounted network disk. After you set up the network disk in Time Machine settings, Time Machine automatically reconnects when it’s time to back up or restore your data.
If your backup disk is on a network, the network server can use SMB file sharing. (Your Mac must be connected to the SMB server when you set up Time Machine.) After you select the network disk in Time Machine settings, Time Machine automatically connects to the disk when it’s time to back up or restore your data.

https://support.apple.com/en-mn/guide/mac-help/mh15139/mac#:~:text=If%20your%20backup%20disk%20is,up%20or%20restore%20your%20data.
Windows does not advertise shares over Bonjour, so they won't automatically appear in the list of possible backup destinations in Time Machine settings. If, after manually mounting the share in the Finder, it still doesn't appear, try the steps in this article:
https://www.imore.com/how-use-time-machine-backup-your-mac-windows-shared-folder

I am unsure how to share the windows volume over smb. I thought it already was, but I'll have to check that again. Does using VMs affect the sharing capability for the Mac to see it as a TM destination drive? Nothing has worked thus far, which is what brought me here.

You don't need to, and legally can't, run macOS in a VM on non-Apple hardware. SMB is the default, and as far as I know the only, native file-sharing protocol on Windows.

I did check the sharing settings and it SMB is turned on. My Mac still does not see the VM drive formatted for Mac as a TM Destination Drive. I do not know what else to do to get this to work. I have even tried using the sparse bundle method and received an error before getting that completed. It seems like everything so far is a dead end. Any further suggestions?

Would you care to give details of what you did and what error message you received?

After I checked that SMB was switch on on the Windows server and on the VM drive (shared) I want to use for the Time Machine task, I went back to my Mac and attempted to get TM to find the destination drive. No matter what I try, I keep getting the error: "No available Time Machine Destinations. Connect to a suitable external hard drive or NAS device."
See next comment for my attempt with installing a sparse bundle on the VM drive for TM.

My coding skills are weak at best (although I have great interest in it), so I turned to AI to assist with installing a sparse bundle on a VM shared drive on the Windows server that would hopefully cause the drive to show up as a suitable TM destination drive. However, it failed. I have the documentation of the "conversation" & the results saved in a .txt file & PDF, but I can't upload either here. There are not enough characters allowed to post in text format in comments. Perhaps someone can give some guidance for sharing these documents that will better explain the attempt/result?

You can post the text by adding to your original question. But why are you trying to back up to a drive shared from a VM? There's no reason to do that. You may not realize that a network backup server doesn't have to be running macOS, and the backup volume doesn't have to formatted as APFS or HFS. In fact, it doesn't matter what the volume format is. TM creates a disk image file on the server that encapsulates an APFS filesystem. That image is mounted on the client, not on the server.

@Link D., how do you figure that the TM backup volume does not have to be formatted as APFS or HFS? I've tried setting up TM on my Mac in every way that I can think of—with Time Machine Settings—such as straight SMB share over LAN, sparse bundle, & formatting a VM as a Mac format, & I keep seeing the same error: "No available Time Machine Destinations. Connect to a suitable external hard drive or NAS device."
I made a mistake in my previous post. I set up a VM for TM, just as I set up separate VMs for other tasks. The files from the VMs are stored in a shared folder on the server, not the VM.

See my edited answer.
